# Android Room Repository - Get User

Tags: java, android, android-room

How I can get a user from the SQLite DB using Room?

DAO - UserDAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =:userID")
Users getUser(int userID);
```

Users Repository - UserClass

```
public Users getUser(final String username) 
{
  return DatabaseClient.getInstance(context).getAppDatabase().usersDao().getUser(username);
}
```

Class where I want to get the user:

```
Users users = new UserClass(context, view).getUser(this.username);
/** How to access to users.getId ???? */
```

Comment: limit the result ->  @Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =:userID LIMIT 1")

Comment: In ur dao the  arguement type is int but in ur repository and other are different .The type mismatch .Better to make same type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your model class use this field.when you insert user.That each user have unic id to insert table

```
class Users{
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "username")
private String userName;

@ColumnInfo(name = "address")
private String address;

 public int getId() {
    return id;
   }

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address =address;
 }
}
```

your Dao Class

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =:userID")
Users getUser(int userID);

@Query("SELECT * FROM users")
List<Users> getAll();

@Insert
void insert(Users users);
```

Your fragment or Activity

List of user you click particular user from recycler view,you get that particular                user model that model id pass to this method.you can get particular user detail.

```
public Users getUser(int userId) 
{
   return DatabaseClient.getInstance(context).getAppDatabase()
      .usersDao().getUser(username);
}
 public List<Users> getAllUser() 
 {
  return DatabaseClient.getInstance(context).getAppDatabase().
    usersDao().getAll();
 }
 public void insert() 
   {
  User user1=new User();
  user1.setUserName("jack");
  user1.setUserAddress("usa");

    DatabaseClient.getInstance(context).getAppDatabase().usersDao().insert(user1);
 }
```